# YML vs Docker CLI config

Tags: docker, traefik

I want configure tlsChallenge in the traefik yml files but unfortunately it doesn't work in my environment. What's going wrong? Both variants hardly differ.

**This works**

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.0/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0-rc3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.email=tester@example.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.mytlschallenge.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=mytlschallenge"
```

**This doesn't work**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  lb:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0-rc3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./lb/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml"
      - "./lb/traefik_dynamic.yml:/traefik_dynamic.yml"
      - "./lb/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    command:
      - "--port=443"
    expose:
      - "443"
```

traefik.yml

```
entryPoints:
  websecure:
    address: :443

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
  
certificatesResolvers:
  mytlschallenge:
    acme:
      email: tester@example.com
      storage: /letsencrypt/acme.json
      tlsChallenge: {} 
      
providers:
  file:
      filename: traefik_dynamic.yml

log:
  level: DEBUG
```

traefik-dynamic.yml

```
http:
  routers:
    whoami:
      rule: Host(`example.com`)
      entrypoints: websecure
      tls:
        certresolver: mytlschallenge
```

Why?

Comment: If you want some help, I've made it work on my repo - '--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=changeme@example.com' - '--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web' - '--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true' - '--entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certresolver=myresolver' https://github.com/tomMoulard/make-my-server/blob/006d014a216eb3b5665b849cd314f7fab516ad16/traefik/docker-compose.traefik.yml#L16-L19 Does logs give you any advice on how to solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: try to use the latest traefik version 2.4.8.